# Is there a way to just get a numerical value out of an Oracle database via a Python run query?

Tags: python, oracle11g

I am very new to scripting and coding in general and am trying to have an application execute a Python script that pulls a session utilization percent value from an Oracle database and runs it against a threshold.  With my current code I am receiving a tuple displayed as '(XX,)' which my application attempts to parse as a number and the final comparison is inaccurate.

I have found a few articles on StackOverflow and used methods such as calling the value by index out of the tuple (like result_handler.update(RESULTS(0)) and taking the result as a string to try and filter out the punctuation. The index to pull the value just returns the entire tuple and the filtering has not worked.

```
import cx_Oracle
...
conn = cx_Oracle.connect("%s/%s@%s:%s/%s" % (USER,PASSWORD,HOST,PORT,INSTANCE))
cur = conn.cursor()
RESULTS = {}
RESULTS['check_percent'] = []

if self.cred_details['cred_type'] == 2 and self.cred_details['db_type'] == 3:

    try:
        cur.execute("SELECT ROUND(current_utilization / CAST(limit_value AS NUMBER) * 100,3) AS processes_percent_used FROM v$resource_limit WHERE resource_name = 'processes'")

        result = cur.fetchall()
        if result:
            RESULTS = {check_percent:[]}
            for index, value in enumerate(result, start=0):
                RESULTS[].append((index, value))

            result_handler.update(RESULTS)
...
```

We just need the actual number back like 23.45 but the result is coming back as a tuple of '(23.45,)'

Comment: What problem are you having? Your question suggests you've already solved it, as all you need to do to get the value is index into the tuple.

Comment: The issue is using index to pull the value just returns the entire tuple, not just the number from the query.  I have updated the question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

For single column fetches you would use a comma like:

```
seqval, = cur.fetchone()
```

See the cx_Oracle tutorial: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/tutorial/Python-and-Oracle-Database-Scripting-for-the-Future.html#L460-L464

I'll let you extrapolate this technique to your code.